# Can my electrical and gas meter be located under an overhang?

Tags: electrical, gas

I'm thinking of adding an extra room above my garage. This would mean I would have a covered area to the front door and the meters would be under the over hang.

Comment: Would your overhang impede on the required 36 inches around each meter?

Comment: This will be location dependent - you need to specify.

Comment: No i wouldn't impede anything. The overhang is just an extension of an upper floor and is exposed to the outside. Thank you for your responses.